# I'm trying to create security question field for my login page

Tags: plugins, multisite

For the last 2 hours I've trying to create a mu plugin that requires the user to answer a question first, so he can login in the website.

It is "What is the name of the white horse of Napoleon?", so the user replies "white" and it should work, by theory. The problem is that it seems it is not getting validated during the login. This is my code:

```
 <?php

add_action( 'login_form', 'add_login_field' );
function add_login_field() { ?>
    <p>
        <label><?php _e('What is the name of the white horse of Napoleon?') ?><br />
        <input type="text" name="user_proof" id="user_proof" class="input" size="25" tabindex="20" /></label>
    </p>
<?php }

add_action( 'login_post', 'add_login_field_validate', 10, 3 );

function add_login_field_validate( $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors) {
    if (!isset($_POST[ 'user_proof' ]) || empty($_POST[ 'user_proof' ])) {
        return $errors->add( 'proofempty', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question.'  );
    } elseif ( strtolower( $_POST[ 'user_proof' ] ) != 'white' ) {
        return $errors->add( 'prooffail', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question correctly.'  );
    }
}

?>
```

I believe the problem is with the part:

```
add_action( 'login_post', 'add_login_field_validate', 10, 3 );
```

Can anyone give me a hand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `login_post` action that I know of - use the `authenticate` filter instead, inside `wp_authenticate()`, called by `wp_signon()`:

```
function wpse_185339_check_user_answer( $user ) {
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {
        if ( empty( $_POST[ 'user_proof' ] ) ) {
            $user = new WP_Error( 'proofempty', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question.' );
        } elseif ( strtolower( $_POST[ 'user_proof' ] ) !== 'white' ) {
            $user = new WP_Error( 'prooffail', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You did not answer the proof-of-humanship question correctly.' );
        }
    }

    return $user;
}

add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wpse_185339_check_user_answer', 100 );
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but don't you think it should validate against something else? Because when I open the login page, the error message is already there.

Comment: This is the only hook I could find for passing errors back to WordPress *and* prevent successful sign in. I would suggest adding a request type check, see edit.

Comment: Is this method safe?
Also, if I input the the answer corretly, but don't fill the user and password field, and submit the form, it will return to the page with no errors, when it actually should say "Incorrect user name or password", but if I input the answer and username, and submit, it will return with the wrong password error. The username error is not appearing because of the `return $user;`?

Comment: Safe in what way? If you want a more rigid solution, check out `wp-login.php` (from line `768` as of 4.1.2) and see how WordPress handles the logic flow.

Comment: That code is being loaded before the `wp-login.php`, it's a mu-plugin. By safe I mean if I can implement it without worrying. Also, why I can't see the error message when the user field is empty?
Sorry for being taking your time.

Comment: Your code gets loaded first, but it *hooks* onto actions that fire later (that's the core principle of WordPress plugins). When the user field is empty, the filter you hook onto isn't fired, so your code doesn't run. Like I say, if you want a more global solution, you'll have to implement some extra hooks that handle different situations, which is why I suggest checking out `wp-login.php` to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: I'll let it be then, I can't understand everything you're talking about :/