# Secruity Questions on a timer

Tags: plugin-development, security, plugin-recommendation, authentication

I am doing some research for a project and one requirement from the client is that to create an account a user must create security questions on account creation. I think this should be easy with a plugin like [Loginizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loginizer/) or [WP Security Question](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-security-questions/).

My main concern is that they want these questions to pop-up as an alert every 20 minutes while logged in and viewing content. This is a requirement by law for this product. I have not been able to find a plugin that would do this and may consider creating one myself.

Is there a hook I can use in WordPress to display this type of thing? Initially, I thought I would store a cookie on login, and after 20 minutes I would make it false, requiring another security question. I would really appreciate some help brainstorming or pointing me in the right direction, as I cannot find much on this topic. [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185339/im-trying-to-create-security-question-field-for-my-login-page) question was somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 'timer' has to execute on the client side, then you will need to find some JavaScript that will 'run' the timer and pop up the box.

You can't do this with PHP code (WP filters, hooks, themes, plugins), because PHP runs on the server, not the browser.

Browser side stuff has to be done with JavaScript...and the client (visitor's browser) needs to have JavaScript enabled.  (Although you could create a plugin that runs the JavaScript code on all pages...)

But the solution is some client-side JavaScript code.